# How to change the default structure generation of single post permalinks?

Tags: wordpress, url-rewriting, permalinks

I want to change the output of `the_permalink()` function and the likes. So, I don't want to change the mermalink structure for all the post types, only the 'post' post type, and only the single page.

I already changed the rewrite rules so that

```
mysite.com/news/2016/the-news-title
```

will drive the user to the single post page template and display content properly. Fine.
Now, as I said, I want `the_permalink()` function to generate links with that structure.

How could I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok following Noman indications, I can post my own answer. I could the 'the_permalink' filter and modify the output if post_type == 'post'. The basic code:

```
add_filter('the_permalink', 'edit_the_permalink', 10, 2);
function edit_the_permalink($permalink, $post) {
  // you should pass the post object when calling the_permalink()
  if(is_object($post) && $post->post_type == 'post'){
    // [...do the magic...]
    return $permalink;
  }
}
```

Please note that both `the_permalink()` and `get_permalink()` (alias `get_the_permalink()`) accept the $post argument and you should pass it as a post object.

Also, note that you can do pretty much the same with the `post_type_link` filter if you want modify the custom post types permalink generation (output of `get_post_permalink()`). In this case the callback will receive 4 parameters: $post_link, $post, $leavename, $sample.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find a proper solution but you can generate your permalink here for post type `post` you have `$post` **WP_Post Object** ..
Why use `get_post()` because `post_name` (permalink) is saved in this field and it will always unique.

```
function edit_the_permalink($permalink) {
    $post = get_post(array('post_name' => $permalink));
    if( $post->post_type == 'post' ) {
        // Override your permalink here for post_type = `post`
        echo '<pre>';print_r($post);echo '</pre>';
        $permalink = '';
        return $permalink;
    }
}
add_filter('the_permalink', 'edit_the_permalink', 10, 1);
```

Comment: Thank you, but are you really sure? post_name is used for the slug (in fact, it is the slug): the permalink is a composition of more pieces where the slug is only the last one.

Comment: Also, the_permalink filter accepts 2 parameters, the second being the post, so no need for get_post. Please correct your answer and then I can upvote ;)
Anyway, I get the thing, this filter is suitable for what I need, I can just properly build the permalink. Thank you.

Comment: @Stratboy i have tested my code before posting here. in my case the second parameter is returning `0` thats why i used `get_post` for permalink.. yes the **the permalink is a composition of more pieces** and post_name always be unique so don't worry about using get_post.. well i glad that i help you to find a way. :) Thanks :)

Comment: it returns 0 because you're not passing the post object. Please see the docs: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_permalink and the source code in  wp-includes/link-template.php